# Mozilla automatically adding disabled="" as button attribute

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mozilla

I have issue I'm making asp .net application any on my view page I got problem.

When I run application in Chrome everything works perfect, but when I run it in Mozilla it just somehow add's **disabled=""** on my button - when I see page source attribute is added.

Here's my button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btnBid" value="Bid" type="button" id="@Html.Raw("btn" + item.IDAuc)">
    Bid 
</button >
```

Comment: Show us the CSS of `btn`, `btn-warning` and `btnBid`

Comment: I've editted now to class="btnBid" and still it happens. My class btnBid is empty, I've set it up only because I've assigned on click function:  $('.btnBid').click(function (event) { ... }

Comment: Can you add a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for the same as your code seems to be OK

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/9wd49yb1/ I should need only staff about button, other template codes for view aren't important so the result looks not pretty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this happened, but as one solution I've called `initialize()` function in JavaScript in which I've just set all buttons' class to be `btn` and simply just call:

```
$(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
```